# Can the form action attribute call a javascript function in an external javascript file?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have the form tag written as such:

```
<form id="form" action="mail.php" method="post"><!--form here--></form>
```

Currently this poses some problems, so I am switching the form action to an AJAX solution, however, I would like the AJAX function to be in an external JavaScript file. I know that you can link the form action attribute to a file, but how would I tell the form to look at the specific function in the file?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

just include the script file using `<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" />` and call the function in file wherever you want... you don not need to tell the program where to look for function .. all the script code is included within the file with the use of `<script>`

Comment: so I can just write formSubmit() in that action attribute and it will search the javascript file I attached and run that function?

Comment: yup ! It will do so, It always does

Comment: that's why I was asking to make sure I could use external js file

Comment: I am not telling you to keep javacript code inline.. what I am saying is to keep it in separate .js file and call that file.

Comment: When you attach an event inline inside the form tag it's still inline JS even though you have your function in an external file

Comment: that I understand but, I think this is quick way to do this with no harm done ;)

Comment: do this: document.getElementById("form_id").onsubmit = MySubmitFunction;
place it in a script tag below the form tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
onsubmit="SubmitFormViaAjax();return false;"
```

This way the form won't submit itslef (return false) and you can use any function in the included form to submit the form's data directly to the recipient via ajax.

Just make sure to include the ajax functions file in the page.

Comment: by "in the page" you mean in the html file or in the javascript file..?

Comment: It isn't a good idea to use inline JavaScript. Don't put it in the HTML file.

Comment: Somewhere in the HTML have <script src=""></script>

Comment: Another approach would be use event registers, but this is defiantly the easiest while working with pre-existing form